# f95_precision.mod on Debian

Tags: linux, fortran, debian, intel, intel-mkl

I'm trying to use the Intel MKL library from a fresh install of Debian 11.
I'm looking to use the Debian installation of MKL instead of installing manually.

A simple program like

```
program main
  use f95_precision
  write(*,*) "hello world"
end program main
```

compiled with

```
mpifort -m64 -I/usr/include/mkl/intel64/lp64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mkl -Wl,--no-as-needed -lmkl_gf_lp64 -lmkl_sequential -lmkl_core -lpthread -lm -ldl -o test test.F90
```

fails with error

```
f951: Fatal Error: Reading module ‘/usr/include/mkl/intel64/lp64/f95_precision.mod’ at line 1 column 2: Unexpected EOF
```

Typical error when the f95_precision.mod file has been generated with another compiler.

What is the right way to use the file f95_precision when using the Debian package installation of MKL?

Edit: I know I can download MKL from the Intel site, install it,  compile the blas95 and lapack95 interfaces and then use the f95_precision.mod generated then. That works. The point of this post is to know how do I use the already existing f95_precision.mod, blas95.mod and lapack95.mod that a fresh Debian installation provides.

Comment: MKL is available for free in Intel oneAPI.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the post to focus on solving the problem.

Comment: OK, so which compiler is mpifort? Which version? Which version is the MKL library? Did you use these packages? https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/intel-mkl

Comment: Thank you. 
The configuration is such that mpifort redirects to gfortran.
It's a fresh Debian bullseye(stable) installation, the versions of packages are available here: https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/allpackages
I used the intel-mkl-full package.
I think I just might not know how to use the f95_precision.mod file that comes with the debian package installation.

Comment: Did you follow the link advisor? Did you set the MKL paths correctly before using? https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/onemkl-link-line-advisor.html#gs.8r5wph  You must point to tge right module version. There are multiple versions of modules available.

Comment: Thank you. I followed the link advisor. As it is a fresh Debian installation, all,the .mod files are in /usr/include/mkl , there is only one f95_precision.mod file.

Comment: In that case it might be a module file for a different (perhaps Intel) compiler.

Comment: Thank you. That's why I commented that it is a typical error of a file generated by a different compiler. But that would mean that the Debian MKL package is broken since it does not deliver the files to generate my own f95_precision.mod file, and the one it does deliver does not work with the gfortran compiler. Therefore, a dependency issue.

Comment: My guess is that I am not using it right, and there is a way to use it with gfortran.

Comment: My guess is that the module files are rarely used so no-one noticed that they included the ones for a different compiler. So I suspect a packaging bug. Try the Intel compiler with them and see (available in OneAPI). Or just open the .mod file and tell us what you see at the start of the file.

Comment: @Astor could you please try with mpiifort and see if it works?

Comment: @Vidyalatha_Intel I tried and it doesn't work for me. And I think it kind of makes sense, those .mod files have to be created with the same compiler. This looks like a packaging issue for me, like Vladimir says.
Either the Debian package has to compile the .mod with the existing gfortran, and recompile if gfortran changes, or those .mod files do not have to be packaged.

Comment: Hi @Astor, i tried with this command and it worked mpiifort -m64 -I/opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2022.1.0/include/intel64/lp64/ -L/opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/latest/lib/intel64 -Wl,--no-as-needed -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_sequential -lmkl_core -lpthread -ldl -o test test.F90 -lm